# Vagrant start docker container after halt

Tags: vagrant, docker, vagrantfile, boot2docker

I am using Vagrant boot2docker to provision docker containers.
This containers are created and started during the provision process.

After halting or restarting the VM and then calling `vagrant up` the containers are not restarted again.

Also `vagrant provision` does not work a second time because the containers all have a fixed name to the provision process can not run again.

Is there a way in Vagrant where I can restart containers on `vagrant up`

Answer (score 1):

These are not a Vagrant problem per se.

1) Docker by default won't start your containers on boot. You can achieve this by using [Docker's restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/).

2) If you use simple provision methods such as bash script, you should know that these are not [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) - meaning they will run again, even if the desired state is already achieved (in your case, the state is "running containers"). So you'll need to use CM tools such as Puppet/Chef/Ansible/etc that are able to check your container state before trying to launch them.

Comment: This link https://docs.docker.com/sorry/#/articles/host_integration/ is not working. Can you please check?